# Send parameter to servlet

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsp, servlets

I have a page that show the results of a search. In that page there is a table that contains the file to download a option to delete the file. If you click in the file name it will download the file but if you click on delete it will delete the file.
For security reasons you need a password to delete the file. This password needs to be verified on the server.
When you click on delete it shows a modal window asking for the password.
Now my problem is how I send the password and the id of the file that I want to delete to the servlet? Because when I click on delete the modal window have no information of the id of the file.

The results in a table like:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td><a href="?id=11"</td>
      <td><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Delete!</a></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Maybe you should make the user login ahead of time and not even see the delete button if not logged in. Then in the servlet, you already know if they're logged in or not and if their username has permissions, from the session.

Comment: You can use Ajax to validate

Comment: I can't use a login system. @SivaKumar can you explain how?

Answer (score 0):

use data-id attribute to hold file id and retrieve it on click event function and pass file id and password to server using AJAX.

Html will look like:

```
<a  class="open-delete-dialog btn btn-danger"
    data-toggle="modal"
    data-target="#myDeleteModal"
    data-id="11">Delete!</a>
<div class="modal hide" id="myDeleteModal">
 <div class="modal-header">
    <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
    <h3>Enter Password to delete the file: <span id="fileId"></span></h3>
  </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Password:</p>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password"/>
    </div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button"
            class="btn btn-default"
            data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button id="submit" type="button" 
            class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
//set fileId to the modal
$(document).on("click", ".open-delete-dialog", function () {
     var myFileId = $(this).data('id');
     $(".modal-header #fileId").val( myFileId );     
});

//get fileId and password and make AJAX post   
$('button#submit').click(function(e){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'your servlet url',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {password: $('.modal-body #password').val(),
               fileId: $('.modal-header #fileId').val()
              },
        success: function(response) {
            //show response to user
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, e) {
            alert('error'+e);
        }
      });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

finally in Servlet#doPost() method get password and fileId like:

```
String password = request.getParameter("password");
String fileId = request.getParameter("fileId");

//Here, do your delete and return response back
```

Comment: thanks for the help. This works perfectly but I have a small problem. My file ids are all like: 0xe713ebb7336ff7096430b22124e4641952b4dc1f.                         So when it reads the value is always 0.

Comment: @esfomeado12 update your question with the problem what you facing. the code how you written to read file id.